# Visual Studio Build Project and run on post build event

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, build-process

I have a project lets call it "MyLib.lib". I have another project that tests all the functionality of that project. Lets call it "TestMyLib.exe".

I would like to make it so that whenever MyLib.lib is built it runs TestMyLib.exe as a post build step.

So normally I would just add a post build event that runs TestMyLib.exe. The problem is that this project needs to be built as well and has a dependency on MyLib.lib.

So I have a bit of a circular dependency problem.

> I would like to know how to build TestMyLib.exe after MyLib.lib is
>   built and then run TestMyLib.exe. Both projects are in the same
>   solution.

Comment: Why don't you just set the post build event on Exe, make the Exe dependent on Lib, and whenever you are about to build the Lib, you actually build the Exe (and its dependencies incl. Lib, and its post build events incl. the test). Without cyclic dependencies. Profit.

Comment: Because if people do not have to run the test they will not do it. I want to force the run of the tests. If you want to build a new version of this product it better pass all the tests.

Comment: You do have a point, but: to make sure the tests run, for all possible configuration/platform options, you're better of (and safer, and more certain) not relying on people to run tests but on a build server of some kind. Apart from that: what @mainactual proposes is actually rather common. Have lib projects and test projects in one solution, configured so that the tests build after the libs and run their exe in postbuild. So when the solution is built, tests also run.

Comment: We have a build server, but people still get in the habit of building and sending someone a hot fix from their local machine. That is exactly what I am trying to do?? It is all in one solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msbuild TestMyLib.vcxproj /p:Configuration=$(Configuration) /p:Platform=$(Platform)` on the command line in post build event.